# Не запускается компилятор Rust

Tags: компилятор, rust

Привет народ, подскажите пожалуйста, не могу скомпилировать и даже просто выполнить `rustc --version`, пишет

> Точка входа в процедуру AcquireSRWLockExclusive не найдена в библиотеке DLL KERNEL32.dll.

ОС Windows XP SP3 x86, компилятор установщик качал с официального сайта.

Comment: Эта функция [появилась в Vista](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681930%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), так что думаю, вы не вписываетесь в system requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Только вчера появилась поддержка XP

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь давать чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Это не поддержка как таковая, это некоторый прогресс в этом направлении. Официально поддерживаются 7 и дальше.